# fieldPermissions is null in the PermissionSet instance

Tags: metadata-api, field-permissions

I created a class to update field permission via Apex class few years back.

Please refer snippet below:

```
MetadataService.MetadataPort service = new MetadataService.MetadataPort();
service.SessionHeader = new MetadataService.SessionHeader_element();
service.SessionHeader.sessionId = UserInfo.getSessionId();
List<String> permissionSetNamesArray = new List<String>();
permissionSetNamesArray.add('My Permission Set');

List<MetadataService.PermissionSet> perm = 
    (List<MetadataService.PermissionSet>) service.readMetadata('PermissionSet'
                                                        , permissionSetNamesArray).getRecords();
MetadataService.PermissionSet quickPerm = perm.get(0);
System.debug('quickPerm.fieldPermissions=' + quickPerm.fieldPermissions);//This is coming null
```

I am trying to test my class again but getting issue.

While debugging I found the **fieldPermissions** is null in the **MetadataService.PermissionSet**.

I have updated to the new MetadataService version(v42.0), but still getting the error.
Can someone please guide me here.

Comment: I have tried the code you shared and it's working fine for a custom permission set but not for a standard permission set.

Comment: is `'MetadataService' a 3rd party open source code set?  Have you posted to the Issues on the Github?

Comment: @MukulMahawariya It is still coming null. I am trying on custom permisison set.

Comment: @DavidCheng It is BSD-3 licensed code. Not posted on Github: https://github.com/certinia/apex-mdapi

Comment: Found the root cause. I was using the permission set name but API name should be used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

API Name of the permission set should be used instead of name:

```
MetadataService.MetadataPort service = new MetadataService.MetadataPort();
service.SessionHeader = new MetadataService.SessionHeader_element();
service.SessionHeader.sessionId = UserInfo.getSessionId();
List<String> permissionSetNamesArray = new List<String>();
permissionSetNamesArray.add('My_Permission_Set');//Change like this

List<MetadataService.PermissionSet> perm = 
    (List<MetadataService.PermissionSet>) service.readMetadata('PermissionSet'
                                                        , permissionSetNamesArray).getRecords();
MetadataService.PermissionSet quickPerm = perm.get(0);
System.debug('quickPerm.fieldPermissions=' + quickPerm.fieldPermissions);//This is not coming null now
```